# billing issue on app engine with increase after shutdown the project

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

I'm new to google cloud. I have made a project about flask TensorFlow, then I run on app engine, not over 24 hours. I shut down the project, but billing is still increasing. I don't know why.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

During the time the application is running, do you have any traffic or are you using the project to do some work? I you are no doing any work, check your logs and see if your have any activity. If you have the`billing.accounts.getSpendingInformation` role, check this document [1].  The documents lets you check your billing reports.

Also monitor your CPU usage by clicking on your instances name on GCP, look for the monitoring tab.  With this feature your can check your CPU usage, I had an application that was doing some extra work and Google was billing me for that extra CPU work.  I checked the CPU utilization and I was able to determine what was the issue and fix it.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports

Answer (score 0):

Some charges can continue to be incurred on Google App Engine even after shutting down the project.

> #### Disabling an application
>
> Disable an App Engine application to stop your app from running
> instances and serving requests. No data loss will occur when you
> disable your app, nor will any configuration settings change. Simply
> re-enable your App Engine application to startup instances and
> continue serving the traffic to your app.
>
> Your app's resources in both the standard and flexible environment are
> disabled and therefore won't incur charges, however billing charges
> can still occur for the other services in your Cloud project, for
> example you can still incur storage charges for your stored data.
>
> To disable an App Engine application:
>
> 1. Go to the [Application settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings) page.
> 2. Click **Disable application** and then follow the prompts.
>
> When you want your app to continue serving requests, enable the App
> Engine application by returning to the same Application settings page
> and then clicking Enable application.

<sub>Source documentation: [Setting up your Google Cloud project for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console)</sub>